# SMTP server on windows server 2016 doesn't deliver the mails

Tags: smtp, windows-server-2016

I have installed a SMTP server on a Windows server 2016 hosted on amazon. When I tried testing the mail servicewith the powershell command:

```
Send-MailMessage -SMTPServer localhost -To (my mail) -From admin@mail.fr -Subject "Test Mail" -Body "This is a test"
```

Sometimes it work with the localhost in parameter but when i try with the public ip or the domain name it always make an error:
[image: error]

I followed lots of different configuration tutorial for the SMTP server, opened the firewall and all ports on the AWS security group but the result is always the same.

Here is the configuration of my server:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hope you can help me resolve this issue, thanks for your help !

Comment: Enable logging and then review the logs.

Comment: After your comment, I enabled the logs but I don't have any logs in the folder where they are supposed to be.